# fetch current time in AM or PM using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

get the current time in 12 hr format using `moment.js`

currently i am trying to fetch the hrs and mins as follows , but current code is returning only hrs and min i want AM and PM too based on current tiime

```
getHrMin:function(){

            var currentDate = moment();
            var data = currentDate.format("hh:mm").split(":");

            if(data.length >0 )
                return {"hrs":data[0], "min":data[1]};
            else
                return null;


        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/), mentioned on the moment website, the format to receive AM or PM notation is **a** or **A** which returns the am or pm format in small letters(a) or capital letters(A).

So in your case, you could do

```
    currentDate.format("hh A:mm").split(":")
```

in order to get the am or pm format.

The value passed to format function above depends on how you want to format it.

In the above case the format will return something like **11 AM:30** and when you split it by colon(:), you will receive 2 elements in array, first will be **11 AM** and second will be **30**. In case you don't want the AM or PM value with the hour value , you could do

```
  format("hh:A:mm")
```

Hope that helps!